# How can I get rid of annoying "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" autocomplete suggestion on Visual Studio Code Intellisense

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pdb

Most of the time, Intellisense on VSC is really convenient, pressing 'enter' to autocomplete variables, functions etc. So I don't want to get rid of it completely.

But I find it INCREDIBLY jarring when I'm closing parentheses, pressing enter, and the autocomplete always suggests and enters one of these two useless snippets of codes:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

(the same thing happens here trying to import pandas as pd)

or

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

I want to keep autocomplete upon pressing enter ON for things like variables and function suggestions, and preferably remove the above from the suggestions altogether if possible. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: -What language service are you using? In my test, the result did not show "import pdb" or "pdb.set_trace()". Have you used other modules and settings?

Comment: Python 3+. The main problem is just this being the typing suggestion upon closing parentheses in VSCode. The optimal solution would be to block specific suggestions from Intellisense whilst typing.

Comment: I mean what is the "python.languageServer" you use in "settings.json", have you tried using different language services? In my test, "Intellisense" did not show "import pdb" or "pdb.set_trace()".

Answer (score 0):

If it is a code snippet that gets applied here, you can use the `editor.snippetSuggestions` in your settings and set it to `none` if you want to hide snippets from intellisense.

You can also modify the sorting of the suggestions though if it helps in your specific usecase. more details can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_snippets-in-suggestions